# how to read file from the specificed location

Tags: c#

```
if (File.Exists(Path))
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        this.LoadReport(stream);
    }
}
```

Path file having read only permission only. Got exception while reading, if I remove read only attribute from file properties working. How to resolve this one? 
Access to the path 'path' is denied. Got this exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try define `FileAccess` this way:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```

Added:
`FileShare.Read` is default so this is enough:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

[FileStream Constructor (String, FileMode, FileAccess) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft.aspx).

Comment: @Michael : Anachu --- super